# ¿Que hacer cuando alguien coge la respuesta de otro usuario?

Tags: discusión, soporte

Me explico, un usuario realizó una pregunta la cual fue contestada desde los comentarios, pero unos minutos después otro usuario cogió lo que se había comentado, lo organizó y lo publicó como respuesta, creo que es claro en este caso que fue un plagio por decirlo de alguna manera, que se debe hacer en casos así ?

Comment: Hola, esto seria para ganar privilegios o medallas, con algun interes de ese tipo. Estado repasando las normas de publicacion y no puede ser mas que para su beneficio, abria que ver si se hizo con buena o mala intencion.                      Un saludo.